# ogre3d integrate (fast but not realtime) raytracing

Tags: real-time, raytracing, ogre3d

I am using Ogre3D in a realtime application (C++). The application has to run on as many platforms as possible: platforms without powerful graphic cards or even on virtual systems (vbox, vmware). So the idea is to make only a few effects (shadows, floor reflections), with Ogre3D (shaders etc.) in realtime but also offer the possibility to get a raytraced image of high quality not in realtime. The constraint is that the raytrace image should not take more than up to 30sec to render. The raytracing need not to be perfect, but reflections (1-2 trace depth), shadows, ambient occlusion would be nice. What toolkits meet these conditions? Does anyone know an SDK for ray tracing that can be easily integrated. It might be software rendering or raytracing on GPU.

So far I have looked at: LuxRender (http://www.luxrender.net/en_GB/index) and RedSDK http://www.redway3d.com/pages/redsdk.php. I am not sure wether LuxRender can do quite fast images (must not be realtime but also not several minutes) and if it can be integrated. Does anyone have experiences with this?

Answer (score 2):

> So far I have looked at: LuxRender
>   (http://www.luxrender.net/en_GB/index) and RedSDK
>   http://www.redway3d.com/pages/redsdk.php. I am not sure wether
>   LuxRender can do quite fast images (must not be realtime but also not
>   several minutes) and if it can be integrated. Does anyone have
>   experiences with this?

You may want to check LuxRays (http://www.luxrender.net/wiki/LuxRays) and in particular SLG (http://www.luxrender.net/wiki/SLG). Now they are both part of LuxRender and SLG has been packed in a library so it can be used in other applications too. You can find a demo video of SLG3 at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jk-N4f9ze4k

SLG supports CPU-only (Path tracing, Bidirectional path tracing, BiDir+VM, etc.) and OpenCL rendering modes (Path tracing and a RT/low-latency Path tracing).

All the software is available in source form under GPL license.

Answer (score 0):

OpenRL will do this and since it's close to OpenGL should be straightforward to integrate into Ogre, since you can construct the data in similar fashion: -- see the documentation links at https://www.caustic.com/docs.php

It's also amenable to (but doesn't require) hardware acceleration....